# JQuery Validation plugin success function on submit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been trying to make a form which, once validated, sends an email and returns a "sent" message on the same screen. In other words I need to somehow combine the action of:

```
$('#mailForm').on('submit', function(){
$("#formContainer").html("Thanks! Your message has been sent.")
$.post($(this).attr('action'));
  return false;
});
```

with:

```
$('form').validate();
```

Reading, I have an idea it should be something like this:

```
$("#mailForm").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form){
     $("#mailForm").ajaxSubmit();  
     $("#formContainer").html("Thanks! Your message has been sent."); 
     return false; 
   };
 });
```

But this just breaks the page, so is clearly nonsense. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you should write your code as

```
$('#mailForm').validate({

    ... your validation rules come here,

    submitHandler: function(mailForm) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            data: $(mailForm).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                $("#formContainer").html("Thanks! Your message has been sent.");
            }            
        });
    }
```

});

Comment: Thanks - is there something I can add to stay on the same page though? I'm being taken to my /email.php page on submit. My "return false" did that before I tried the jQuery Validation plugin, but when I add it in here it does not work...

Comment: what you given as your form action..?

Comment: change your form element as <form action=" " method="post"></form>